# Firebase Scheduled Cloud Function Not Triggering After Code and Dependency Updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I recently updated my Firebase Cloud Functions project by adding new dependencies and changing some existing code. Since these updates, my scheduled Cloud Function to update a database every 20 minutes has stopped working. I've tried reverting to an older version of the project where it was working, but the issue persists.

Here are the main changes I made:

1. Added openai dependency to functions/package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
  "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
  "openai": "^4.22.1"
}
```

2. Created a new route openAiRouter in functions/src/index.ts and its corresponding implementation in openAiRouter.ts.
3. Modified spaceDevsRouter.ts by exporting the updateDatabase function and removing the setInterval(updateDatabase, 1200000) line. Instead of setInterval I am using the scheduled cloud function

```
// Import Firebase functions and admin modules
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import { updateDatabase } from "../routes/spaceDevsRouter";

// Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
admin.initializeApp();

// Scheduled Cloud Function to update database every 5 minutes
export const scheduledSpaceEventUpdate = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 5 minutes")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    console.log("Scheduled update of space events started");
    try {
      await updateDatabase();
      console.log("Scheduled update of space events completed successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during scheduled update of space events:", error);
    }
  });
```

After using this scheduled cloud function everything was working just fine. It was updating my database the way it was supposed to. Then, I added the openai API and added the api key to `.runtimeconfig.json`, but the openai API addition seemed completely unrelated to me. I tried to run it locally with this `"serve:dev": "npm run build && concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"firebase emulators:start --only functions\"",`
It did not work locally nothing updating and no console logs that I set up for testing were being hit. I tried to deploy it with this script `"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",`
After deploying I checked my project in google cloud and it says in the Cloud Scheduler that  'No Cloud Scheduler jobs to display
Jobs you create will appear here.'

Next I tried to load an older commit where it was working and tried locally with the emulator and then tried to deploy and neither works and I am totally lost on how to solve this.
[GitHub Repository for this project](https://github.com/TheodoreRed/Space-Explorer-Backend)

Comment: To run locally you'll have to use `connectFunctionsEmulator` and for admin calls to route to the emulator you'll need to set an environment variable. See:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore